# php gratuity calculator error

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a gratuity calculator in php, that when I enter in the bill amount and then the tip percentage that will return the results with the total amount;

I would like it to be displayed on a table with Bill Amount:, Tip Amount and Total Amount.

but having trouble with my code working it keeps giving me an error saying object not found!, this is my code so far.

```
 <html>
<body>
    <h2>Tip Calculator</h2>
    <form action="res.php" method="post">
        <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Bill Amount:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="bill" value="0" /></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>Tip Percent:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="tip_percent" value="0"/></td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calculate" /></td>
    </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['bill'], $_POST['tip_percent'])){
if(is_numeric($_POST'bill']) && is_numeric($_POST['tip_percent'])){
        echo "Bill: ".$_POST['bill'];
        if($_POST['tip_percent']<0) 
            $_POST['tip_percent'] = 0; 
        echo "<br/>Tip %: ".$_POST['tip_percent'];
        echo "<br/>Tip Amount: ".$tip = number_format($_POST['bill'] * $_POST['tip_percent'] / 100, 2);
        echo "<br/>Total Amount: ".$total = $tip+$_POST['bill'];
    }else echo "At least one of the values was not a number!";
}else echo "At least one of the values was missing!";
?>
```

Comment: please mention what error you are getting

Comment: _'it keeps giving me an error'_ - so why didn't you post it here?

Comment: You're using a `method="post"` but you're trying to read the fields as `$_GET` so you will get undefined index error.

Comment: I see I changed it to POST and I still get an object not found! error

Comment: @852saber sorry buddy, helped you with what was clearly visible with your code, if you want further help update your question with the full error message you're getting and provide as much information as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing the syntax error:

```
if(is_numeric($_POST'bill'])
                    ^
```

With:

```
if(is_numeric($_POST['bill'])
```

You're missing a square bracket at the beginning of `'bill']`